# Reliability of PHP copy() method with image file from remote server

Tags: php, linux, apache, file-upload, copy

http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php

Makes a copy of the file source to dest.

After conduction several tests, the PHP copy() method works fine to copy an image file from a remote server. The image file is coped from the public html directory on the remote server, where the website images exist.

Would this method be reliable in all cases? In other words, are there any known configurations that may exist on the remote server that would cause copy() to fail.

```
<?php copy("http://domain.com/images/file.jpg", "/local_dir/file.jpg"); ?>
```

cURL has been suggested but seems like overkill to perform a simple copy operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably fail if the image was not readable, but since you said it's accessible to the public, that shouldn't be a problem.